# C++ + SDL Program just stops

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I am trying to use SDL to create a game. It all worked perfectly but it just stopped working. I use SDL_Init to init everything but it just stops.

```
std::cout << "Before INIT" << std::endl;

//Start SDL
if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0)
{
    std::cout << "SDL could not initialize." << std::endl;
}
else
{
    std::cout << "SDL could init" << std::endl;
}
```

The above code is what I am trying to start and this is the console output:

```
Before INIT
```

If it replace the SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING with individual settings it seems to stop working with:

```
    SDL_INIT_JOYSTICK
    SDL_INIT_GAMECONTROLLER
```

What I am using:

```
Windows 10
Visual Studio 2017
SDL2-devel-2.0.9-VC
All I use is the SDL2 version from the website.
```

My visual studio also put out this but hasn't helped my find and solution:

```
The thread 0x840 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1784 has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
The thread 0x42d4 has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
The thread 0x23c8 has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
The thread 0x4330 has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
The thread 0x3fe4 has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
The thread 0x42f4 has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
The thread 0x1410 has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
The thread 0x3a14 has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
The program '[2552] ice-game.exe' has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
```

I am hopefull someone might help me to get this working!

Comment: OS?  Compiler?  [MCVE]?  SDL2 version?  Self-compiled SDL2 or binary?  If binaries, from where?

Comment: @genpfault Hi, I have tried and give some extra information. The code exampled above is everything needed to get the result of the application not doing anything after the SDL_Init line.

Comment: Try dropping back to 2.0.8; 2.0.9 drastically overhauled how joysticks are handled and given that you narrowed down the misbehaving subsystems to JOYSTICK & GAMECONTROLLER I suspect that's where the problem is.

Comment: Will try that thank you!